# How Do I Remove Left Pane Fields in Docusign API

Tags: api, docusignapi

I wanted to remove left panel fields from docusign pdf. Could some one please assist. 
Whenever I transfer a case to another approver I see the left pane info.

Eg-Scenario:

1. A case is assigned to 2 people lets say A and B,according to current docusign functionality when A opens the case to sign the document he will not see the left pane fields[Signature,initial,name,datesigned etc..,]
2. Because of some dependencies if A transfer the case to C who is having same privileges. When C opens the case and tries to sign in the document, then we are able to see Left Pane Fiels[Signature,initial,name,datesigned etc..,]

Any suggestions about this behaviour will help us.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the DocuSign [Free Form Signing](https://www.docusign.com/blog/quick-tip-tuesday-guided-signing-versus-free-form-signing/).

> **Free-form signing occurs** when no tags are placed on a document submitted via DocuSign. This means that the signer will be presented with a palette of signature options (Signature, Initial, Full Name, etc.) which can be applied to the document at will.

To prevent Free form signing, just place a tab on the document your are sending.